# Set color of the boxes in a boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
hist <- ggplot(df, aes(x = A,fill = ("red"))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  ggtitle("Treatment") + theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5), text = element_text(size = 20)) + 
  scale_fill_manual("A", values = c("0" = "dodgerblue4", "1" = "chocolate"))
    
hist
```

[image]

I need help regarding setting the colors of the boxplots from the ggplot2 package which I am learning right now. I want the left one to be in the blue color and the right one in the other color. But unfortunately I cannot figure out how to set these instead this code just sets the right colors in the Legend and leaves the boxes unchanged?!

Comment: Try replacing `fill = ("red")` by `fill = factor(A)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Rene said it is a bit hard to help while not seeing the dataset.
Looking at the given code your A contains two values you want to color individually
define a vector containing those two values:

```
df_colors <- c("0" , "1")

hist <- ggplot(df, aes(x = A, fill = df_colors )) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  ggtitle("Treatment") + theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5), text = element_text(size = 20)) + 
  scale_fill_manual("A", values = c("0" = "dodgerblue4", "1" = "chocolate"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough code for me to know exactly what you're doing but I think if you remove:

```
mapping = aes(fill = "red")
```

it will solve your problem. A [reprex](https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-create-one/5219) would help others better understand your problem. I think instead you might need something like:

```r
    ggplot(data = your_data) +
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = variable_1, y = variable_2, fill = variable_3), position = "dodge")
```